# Find all old records returning same amount for greater than and less than (> <)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, heroku

I'm trying to find (and then delete) all old records in my DB on heroku.

For some reason these two are equal (notice < and >)

```
Post.find(:all, "updated_at > ?", 30.days.ago).count
Post.find(:all, "updated_at < ?", 30.days.ago).count
```

Makes me hesitent about using the delete.

What call should I make to ensure I do get only the older records?

Comment: It might have to do with the `count()` function at the end....  Also, are you sure that you don't have an equal number of records for before 30 days ago as well as after 30 days ago?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Less than is what you want:

```
Post.find(:all, :conditions => ["updated_at < ?", 30.days.ago])
```

If you're unsure, print some of the records to the console using `p` or awesome_print (`ap`).

Answer (score 16):

The other answers are correct, but for updated ActiveRecord syntax:

```
Post.where("updated_at < ?", 30.days.ago)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify your where clause with :conditions, like so:

```
Post.all(:conditions => ["updated_at < ?", 30.days.ago])
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to delete old records, you want to delete records that have an earlier date, ie,  *less* than the given date (30.days.ago)

Comment: Indeed. The only problem is both calls listed above return the same number. Wonder if it matters that I'm calling on the rails default "updated_at" field rather than my own.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting the records, why don't you set a `state` flag to `pending_delete` and then once you're satisfied you can delete all the records in that state.